# Getting a TypeError when using .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to solve this bug for the past day and have not been able to, can someone help me out!

**Problem:** Getting TypeError: undefined is not object because of props.items.map...

Note: I am getting the value for 'props.items' from 'store/reducers/orders.js'. The dispatch to populate the state in 'store/reducers/orders.js' is called from 'screens/shop/CartScreen.js'. That is where the problem is but I do not see it.

```
props.items.map(cartItem => (
        <CartItem
          key={cartItem.productId}
          quantity={cartItem.quantity}
          amount={cartItem.sum}
          title={cartItem.productTitle}
        />
```

Path: components/shop/OrderItem.js

Link to project: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/SMasood1/Shop

Comment: just place a question mark in front of ```items``` like this: ```props.items?.map(....```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `items` exist before you run `.map()`:

```js
props.items && props.items.map(cartItem => (
        <CartItem
          key={cartItem.productId}
          quantity={cartItem.quantity}
          amount={cartItem.sum}
          title={cartItem.productTitle}
        />
```

Comment: better to check using ```Array.isArray``` too.

Comment: You are correct, 'items' is undefined and does not exist. I am trying to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Maybe because getting the data is asynchronous? If that's the case, the component is rendered for the first time before the data is received that's why. Otherwise, you can try to initialize your store with an empty array for `items` like: `initialState = { items: [], ...other properties}`